# STL "sort()" doesn't sort adequately

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I want to make an array out of a number's digits and then sort it, however when compiling it doesn't sort my array adequately.

**example** : for n = 1432 array is "2, 3, 4, 1"

**NOTE** : m is the number of digits n has (for n=1432 m=4)

The following piece of code extracts every digit and puts it into the v array. Afterwards I sort array v:

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    v[i]=n%10; 
    n/=10;
}
sort(v, v+a);
```

**NOTE** : take a as a copy of n (if m=4, a=n).

After compiling I get the following array "sorted":

> 3 4 1994876145 1

Here's the full code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    
    int i, v[11];
    int w=n, c=n, m=0;
    while(c){
        m++;
        c/=10;
    }
    for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        v[i]=w%10;
        w/=10;
    }

    
    sort(v, v+m);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your **full** program that we can compile, run and point out the errors in your code.

Comment: `i<n` looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: I'm so sorry,  I typo'd, I forgot to add "m". I'm very sorry. It's edited now.

Comment: Is this really your full code? You never assign to the elements of `v`. Reading from `v` is thus Undefined Behaviour, and anything can happen.

Comment: try refreshing? I do assign elements to v

Comment: That code won't compile. `for(i=; i<m; i++)` is... missing something. I can assume it should be zero, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the update, although `for(i=;` is still a typo. Assuming you meant `for(i=0;`, [your code runs just fine](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4b96ceccbec09d7) and I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: yes, it's 0, I just edited it right now... ops

Comment: what is the point of c variable?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/xj484r)

Comment: weird @alterigel, I keep getting the same issue. How can this happen? I run mingw

Comment: @golobitch copy of n to get the number of digits of n

Comment: Please copy and paste your test program.  I don't want to look through your code as I am not sure if I am seeing the same code as you are testing.

Comment: @dr21 but you are not using c anywhere

Comment: @golobitch first loop. it's used to calculate `m`, the number of digits. I concur the loop itself is pointless, as you can do that *and* count the digits *and* store them in a single loop, but it is what it is.

Comment: Seems to run fine here https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/8R8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that I cannot find any issue with your code and from what I can see it is working as it should (at least for me).

However, I would do this in some other way. Like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    while (n > 0) {
        numbers.push_back(n%10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    
    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    
    for (const auto &num : numbers) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Main thing here is that I would use vector instead of array, because I can get rid of calculating how much space I need to store that files, and I do prefer iterators in sort method.

I think that code is very clear and there is no point in explaining it. Your main logic was correct and it stayed the same (get mod 10, and divide our input number with 10).

Comment: The output for any non-positive input is not correct (for 0 it just prints nothing and for `-1113` I wouldn't expect output `-3 -1 -1 -1 `

Comment: @fabian true, this all depends on specifications. I just assumed that input number is positive number. I cannot give him whole solution can I? How would then he learned ;) However, thank you for pointing that our.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd suggest to use `vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    vector <int> v;
    cin>>n;

    while(n != 0){
        v.push_back(n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

if you don't know how to use `vector` then use,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, length = 0;
    cin>>n;
    
    int temp = n;
    while(temp != 0){
        temp /= 10;
        length++;
    }
    
    int v[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        v[i] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    sort(v, v + length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

However, if you want to `handle unexpected values` like `negative` or `string` you can create `validation`.